# Using qTip2 with Handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, handsontable, qtip2

I want to use qTip and Handsontable at the same time.

So I made a grid with Handsontable and when the user submits it, ajax sends the cells that are not correct. Then, with a callback function, I want to color the cells in the wrong format and display a bubble with qTip2.

My problem is when I want to create a bubble on a specific cell, it doesn't work.

Here is my code :

```
function insertTraitementCallback(responseObject,ioArgs)
{
    var jsonobject = eval(responseObject);

    $("td").eq(jsonobject[item]+11).qtip({ //It doesn't work
                content : '<div id="bulle">test</div>'
            });

    for(var item in jsonobject)
    {
        if((item % 2 ) == 0) 
        {
            $("td").eq(jsonobject[item]+11).css("background-color","red"); //It works

        }else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Please help !

Comment: Where is `item` defined within the first call (5th line) to `eq()`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "doesn't work"? What errors or outcome are you getting? What are you expecting?

Comment: Thank you @jthomas for your help but I found my error. My "item" was a string so the bubble was not on any cell.

Comment: just fyi, handsontable has validation on cells which you can use to add a class name (and color) to non-validated cells